# AUCTeX Custom Command broken in new version?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I like to have the auxiliary files in a separate directory, using the following customisation for emacs/AUCTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello world!
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% LaTeX-command: "pdflatex -synctex=-1 -aux-directory auto %s"
%%% End:
```

This worked fine with emacs 24.3.1 and AUCTeX 11.86. But on a new machine I use emacs 25.3.1 and AUCTeX 12.1, and invoking LaTeX with `C-c C-C` gives the following result (the file is `test.tex`):

```
Running `LaTeX' on `test' with 
``pdfpdflatex -synctex=-1 -aux-directory auto "test"  -file-line-error  --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" "test.tex"''
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Evidently, my custom `LaTeX-command` is inserted in another LaTeX command, replacing the "latex" in pdflatex, and of course that gives an error. I could not find out where the other (default?) LaTeX command was defined.

I can work around this by changing the customisation to `%%% LaTeX-command: "latex -aux-directory auto"`, but that seems like a weird hack, and it doesn't work on the other machine I'm using. Is there a smarter way of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is much in the AUCTeX spirit to tune `LaTeX-command` in order to specify that you want to use `pdflatex`. AUCTeX knows about TeX engines and how to activate DVI or PDF mode depending on the engine. See the [documentation of processor options](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Processor-Options.html#Processor-Options), in particular about `TeX-engine`, `TeX-engine-alist` and `TeX-PDF-mode`:

> Command: TeX-PDF-mode
>
> (C-c C-t C-p) This command toggles the PDF mode of AUCTeX, a buffer-local minor mode which is enabled by default. You can customize TeX-PDF-mode to give it a different default or set it as a file local variable on a per-document basis. This option usually results in calling either PDFTeX or ordinary TeX.

[...]

> User Option: TeX-engine
>
> This variable allows you to choose which TeX engine should be used for typesetting the document, i.e. the executables which will be used
>   when you invoke the ‘TeX’ or ‘LaTeX’ commands. The value should be one
>   of the symbols defined in TeX-engine-alist-builtin or
>   TeX-engine-alist. The symbols ‘default’, ‘xetex’, ‘luatex’ and ‘omega’
>   are available from the built-in list.

[...]

> User Option: TeX-engine-alist
>
> Alist of TeX engines and associated commands. Each entry is a list with a maximum of five elements. The first element is a symbol used to
>   identify the engine. The second is a string describing the engine. The
>   third is the command to be used for plain TeX. The fourth is the
>   command to be used for LaTeX. The fifth is the command to be used for
>   the ‘--engine’ parameter of ConTeXt’s ‘texexec’ program. Each command
>   can either be a variable or a string. An empty string or nil means
>   there is no command available.

If you just want to change the engine or PDF vs. DVI mode for the current document, the easiest way is probably to use the *Command → TeXing options* menu, otherwise for your particular options mentioned here (`-synctex=-1 -aux-directory auto`), I believe the following variable is the appropriate one:

> User Option: TeX-command-extra-options
>
> String with the extra options to be given to the TeX processor. For
>   example, if you need to enable the shell escape feature to compile a
>   document, add the following line to the list of local variables of the
>   source file:
>
> ```
> %%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-shell-escape"
> ```
>
> By default this option is not safe as a file-local variable because a
>   specially crafted document compiled with shell escape enabled can be
>   used for malicious purposes.

In your particular case, if you really want to customize the parameters you gave using Emacs file variables, you could use this:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-engine: default
%%% TeX-command-extra-options: "-synctex=-1 -aux-directory=auto"
%%% End:
```

If for instance you would like to use the LuaTeX engine instead of the default (which is normally pdfTeX for LaTeX documents), just replace `default` with `luatex`. In such a case, if AUCTeX detects that you have a LaTeX document, it will compile it with the `lualatex` command, thanks to `TeX-engine-alist-builtin`, which gives the defaults for things you haven't overridden via `TeX-engine-alist`:

```el
TeX-engine-alist-builtin is a variable defined in ‘tex.el’.
Its value is
((default "Default" TeX-command LaTeX-command ConTeXt-engine)
 (xetex "XeTeX" "xetex" "xelatex" "xetex")
 (luatex "LuaTeX" "luatex" "lualatex --jobname=%s" "luatex")
 (omega "Omega" TeX-Omega-command LaTeX-Omega-command ConTeXt-Omega-engine))


Documentation:
Alist of built-in TeX engines and associated commands.
For a description of the format see ‘TeX-engine-alist’.
```

But for the selection of DVI vs. PDF mode, I believe I would rather use the *Command → TeXing options* menu or set the mode globally with something like this in your Emacs configuration:

```el
;; Use nil for DVI mode
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

The following would also work but is less efficient if you have many TeX files opened when you start Emacs, because the hook is run every time for each TeX/LaTeX/etc. file:

```el
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
            #'(lambda ()
                (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)))
```

If you use desktop.el in Emacs, beware that it saves and restores buffer-local values of variables. This can be very confusing when testing Emacs' init config dealing with variables that are automatically buffer-local when set (`TeX-PDF-mode` is one of these, so this applies here).

### Addendum

In order to have AUCTeX use a directory that is different from your `auto` dir and clearly belongs to AUCTeX, you might want to customize `TeX-auto-local` and `TeX-style-local`. I use something like this:

```el
(defun my-TeX-mode-hook ()
  (setq TeX-auto-local "auctex-auto"
        TeX-style-local "auctex-style")
  ;; Use the new dirs in `TeX-style-path' instead of the default ones,
  ;; otherwise AUCTeX won't find them.
  (mapc #'(lambda (arg)
            (when (member (car arg) TeX-style-path)
              (delete (car arg) TeX-style-path)
              (push (cdr arg) TeX-style-path)))
        '(("auto" . "auctex-auto")
          ("style" . "auctex-style"))))

(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'my-TeX-mode-hook)
```

Since it's a bit complicated, though, you may rather choose to rename your `auto` to something else, or accept the possibility that there might be conflicts one day, between what AUCTeX writes there and what your use of `-aux-directory` could cause to be written there (if `-aux-directory` is only about the `.aux` file, it's probably safe).

Comment: Thanks! I had to set `TeX-PDF-mode: nil` to avoid pdfpdflatex, but then `TeX-command-extra-options` did the trick.